# Building Chain of Nodes?

Tags: python, pointers, reference, nodes, chain

I have a Node class. Then I'm building a chain of Nodes.
They are connected with one another via self.prev_node and self.next_nodes,
also the Chain : self.last holds a link to the last element of the chain.
I'm using a method like this to add a new node :

```
class Node(object):

def __init__(self, next_nodes=[], prev_node=None):
    self.next_nodes = next_nodes
    self.prev_node = prev_node


class Chain:

def __init__(self):
   self.start = Node()
   self.last = self.start 

def add_node(self, node):
   node.prev_node = self.last
   self.last.next_nodes.append(node)
   self.last = node
```

The problem is that if I add several nodes :

```
c.start.next_nodes
[Node:2, Node:3, Node:4]

c.start.next_nodes[0].next_nodes
[Node:2, Node:3, Node:4]
```

instead it should be :

```
c.start.next_nodes
[Node:2]


c.start.next_nodes[0].next_nodes
[Node:3]
```

For some reason the next_nodes list seems to be duplicate/the-same.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing mutable "[]" in **init** as a parameter.

So each node you make is referring to the same memory location thus ending up with all same "next_nodes".

Comment: haa.. if I use Node([]) it seems to be OK... where can I read about it ? thanks ... so how can I use default param : [] ?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html) Simple explanation about the behavior.